# ST-Link enumeration failed Error in initializing ST-LINK device. Reason: ST-LINK DLL error

Tags: linux, embedded, stm32

I am using the f446re nucleo board on Linux PopOS to write a simple program that blinks an LED.  When I press debug I keep getting these errors.  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image]

> Error in initializing ST-Link device
>
> Reasong (2) ST-LINK DLL error.

Comment: Hello, please copy/paste error messages or commands instead of including screenshots. This does make easier for people to use the information you provided and therefore increases your chances to get an answer to your question.

Comment: @Frant Not in this case. Without the image I would not know that OP is using CubeIDE with wrong (for Linux configuration)

Comment: @– P__J__ This was far from being clear at  the time I added my comment, since the image was missing, and there was no mention of CubeIDE whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Just choose ST-Link openOCD instead.